# Insert in to join table Spring JPA with Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

My entiti of member:

```
    @Entity(name = "Members")
    data class Member(
            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            val id: Long? = null,

            @Column(unique = true)
            @Basic
            val uid: String,

            @Column(unique = true)
            @Basic val email: String,

            @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
            @JoinTable(name = "groups_members")
            @JsonIgnore
            val groups: Collection<Group?> = ArrayList(),

            @OneToMany(mappedBy = "member")
            @JsonIgnore
            val tasks: List<Task?> = ArrayList(),

            @OneToMany(mappedBy = "creator")
            @JsonIgnore
            val createdTasks: List<Task?> = ArrayList(),

            @OneToMany(mappedBy = "creator")
            @JsonIgnore
            val createdMeetings: List<Meeting?> = ArrayList(),

            @OneToMany(mappedBy = "creator")
            @JsonIgnore
            val createdGroups: List<Group?> = ArrayList(),

            @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])

            @JoinTable(name = "meetings_members")
            @JsonIgnore
            val meetings: List<Meeting?> = ArrayList()
)
```

---

entity of group of members:

```
package com.kotlincoders.tmsapi.data

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore
import javax.persistence.*

@Entity(name = "team")
data class Group(
        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) val id: Long? = null,

        @Column(unique = true, name = "name")
        @Basic
        val name: String,

        @Basic
        val description: String,

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], mappedBy = "groups")
        @JsonIgnore
        val members: List<Member> = ArrayList(),

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group")
        @JsonIgnore
        val tasks: List<Task> = ArrayList(),

        @JsonIgnore
        @ManyToOne val creator: Member
){
        override fun toString(): String {
                return "Group(id=${this.id},name=${this.name},description=${this.description})"
        }
        fun addMember(member: Member){
                members.plus(member)
                member.groups.plus(this)
        }
}
```

Method in controller:

```
@PostMapping("/add/")
fun add(@RequestBody request: AddGroupRequest) {
    val member = memberService.findByUid(request.creatorUid)
    var group = Group(name = request.title, creator = member, description = request.description)
    group.addMember(member)
    groupService.save(group)
}
```

But when i try add member to group i don't have any exception but nothing is inserted to join table and i don know why.
Groups are added succesfully.
I have the same problem with others entities, and i tryed many ways to solve it and nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is related to lazy fetching, to solve that try to use kotlin `allOpen` plugin (More info in the link at the end of the answer).

Using data classes (with `val`) with JPA is not the best option, read this quote from spring example:

> Here we don’t use data classes with val properties because JPA is not designed to work with immutable classes or the methods generated automatically by data classes. If you are using other Spring Data flavor, most of them are designed to support such constructs so you should use classes like data class User(val login: String, …​) when using Spring Data MongoDB, Spring Data JDBC, etc.

https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-kotlin#persistence-with-jpa